# How do you completely delete projects in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, delete-file, projects

So if I go into my selected save folder for my projects and delete my project it no longer shows up in Xcode. However I can still find some other files if I look under my user name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData. There are other files Xcode creates and I'm afraid if I make, and delete a bunch of projects, it is just gonna clutter my Mac with a mess of unneeded files. So how do I completely remove a project in Xcode?
Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 34):

**Xcode 9**

- In Finder, delete the project folder. (If you don't know where it is, open the project in Xcode and right click on project name in the Project Navigator. Choose **Show in Finder**.)
- In Xcode, remove the deleted project from the menu. (Go to **File > Open Recent > Clear Menu**. This will clear all of your recent projects from this menu and the startup menu.)

Answer (score 8):

For Xcode projects in version 11:

1. Open Xcode
2. Click on File
3. Open recent: Clear menu

It will remove all the projects that you have on your Xcode.

Comment: Hi @CShabolotova, and welcome to Stack Overflow. It appears that your answer is providing instruction on how to clear the recent projects list in XCode. But the question was about oprhaned files that XCode creates on the hard drive. Are you sure this method will clear those files?

Answer (score 4):

For Xcode 4, you can go to the Organizer by clicking the button at the top right, and then you'll see your projects. Right click the one you want to remove, and choose "Remove from Organizer..." This will remove all the associated data. I don't know if this is an option in previous versions of Xcode.

Answer (score 4):

### Solution for Xcode 7.3

**To delete Xcode project:**

- Locate the project directory in finder, right-click, and select *Move to Trash*

**To delete Xcode project data:**

- (From the Xcode welcome screen) Go to **Window > Projects**, select the project, then click *Delete* next to the derived data and/or snapshots
- Note: deleting project data can free 50+ MB even from simple projects!

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way I found to do this in Xcode 9.1 was to open Xcode (which may "open" only as an icon on the dock if there are no current projects) and select 'Window' from the Xcode application menu.

Select the 'Welcome to Xcode' option, then click on 'Open another project...' in the right pane of the window.  This should take you to the root of your projects folder in a Finder window.  (Mine end up in /Applications by default.)  From there you should be able to select the project name and 'Move to Trash'.  Empty your trash to get rid of it entirely.

Answer (score 3):

1. Physical deletion : Go to where project folder is. Simply delete folder
   By default it is `Documents/[Project name]`
2. To remove as start-up choice list : 
   On Terminal: `open /Applications/Xcode.app`
   Then
   `File -> Open Recent -> Clear Menu`

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
/Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-UI
```

this is the build folder for your project. You can delete it in finder or in Xcode by pressing Command-Option-Shift-K before delete the project itself.

Answer (score 0):

To Delete XCode Projects in Ver.7.3 you must:

- Open up the Project you would like to delete
- Select the 'Window' option from the Active App Menu for Mac programs. The one where you find - File, Edit, View etc..
- Select the Projects option
- Then you will see a full list of projects
- Highlight the ones you want to remove - Shift + Click >>> Click
- Then Right Click and Select Remove projects

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode Version 8.2 (8C38), you can remove the projects completely (project name in Xcode, programs, data, etc.) one by one by doing the following: [Note:  the instructions are not for just remove the project names from the Welcome Window]

Launch the Xocde and wait until the Welcome window is displayed. The projects will be shown on the right hand side (see below)
[Xcode Welcome Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lSvj.png)

Right click the project you want to remove completely and a pop window [Show in Folder] jumps out; selec it to find out where is the project in the [Finder] (see below)
[Find the project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOcoA.png)

Right click the project folder in the Finder to find it’s path through [Get Info]; use path in the Info window to go to the parent folder, and go to there[Locate the project folder path][3]

Right click the Project Folder (e.g. DemoProject01) and Porject file (DemoProject01.xcodeproj) and select [Move to Trash] ; you will see that (a) the folder in finder is removed AND (b) the Project in the Xcode Welcome Window’s Project List is removed.