# Failed to run application in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile

I was trying to run my first application in Xcode. However, I get the following error. I have no idea how to solve it. I will appreciate any help.

```
 2015-02-08 19:48:05.540 App[6029:512830] CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///Users/xyz/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E8DB0A0F-1F32-453B-84E5-04F6FACEA21B/data/Containers/Data/Application/42230FDC-4FB5-40F2-A3AE-1B35251D0FBF/Documents/Wag.sqlite options:(null) ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134100.)" UserInfo=0x7fe4a0c36fe0 {metadata={
NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;
NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
    Event = <5431c046 d30e7f32 c2cc8099 58add1e7 579ad104 a3aa8fc4 846e97d7 af01cc79>;
};
NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
    ""
);
NSStoreType = SQLite;
NSStoreUUID = "9CDA976B-9D96-47E7-97C0-A6FA3A8002C2";
"_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
}, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store} with userInfo dictionary {
metadata =     {
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
        Event = <5431c046 d30e7f32 c2cc8099 58add1e7 579ad104 a3aa8fc4 846e97d7 af01cc79>;
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "9CDA976B-9D96-47E7-97C0-A6FA3A8002C2";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
};
reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store";
}
2015-02-08 19:48:05.541 Wag[6029:512830] Unresolved error Error Domain=YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN Code=9999 "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" UserInfo=0x7fe4a0c18410 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data., NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to initialize the application's saved data, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe4a0c37060 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134100.)"}, {
NSLocalizedDescription = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data";
NSLocalizedFailureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.";
NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 134100.)\" UserInfo=0x7fe4a0c36fe0 {metadata={\n    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;\n    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {\n        Event = <5431c046 d30e7f32 c2cc8099 58add1e7 579ad104 a3aa8fc4 846e97d7 af01cc79>;\n    };\n    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;\n    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (\n        \"\"\n    );\n    NSStoreType = SQLite;\n    NSStoreUUID = \"9CDA976B-9D96-47E7-97C0-A6FA3A8002C2\";\n    \"_NSAutoVacuumLevel\" = 2;\n}, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store}";
 }
```

Comment: Please add to your question the actual code that causes this error.

Comment: I think it is related to xcdatamodel. However, I don't know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Without some code, the error cannot be understood. Use some breakpoints to find out where in your code this error is being generated.

Answer (score 5):

If you edit the model you defined after you install you app , may cause this crash. Try delete your app , then reinstall and rum again.

Comment: If you want to delete the project from Xcode, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277364/how-do-you-completely-delete-projects-in-xcode

Comment: If you want to delete the app from the simulator or device, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821316/xcode-deleted-images-appear-in-simulator/10880038#10880038

Comment: if my app is live on the store then i don't want everyone to delete the app and reinstall again. The correct solution is migration